# How to use Terraform `google_app_engine_domain_mapping` with service account?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a GCP App Engine domain mapping via Terraform with the following configuration:

```
provider "google" {
  version = "3.36.0"
  region  = var.region
}

resource "google_app_engine_domain_mapping" "domain_mapping" {
  project = local.project_id
  domain_name = var.domain_name

  ssl_settings {
    ssl_management_type = "AUTOMATIC"
  }

  depends_on = [
    google_app_engine_application.backend_app
  ]
}
```

Terraform is configured to use an organization level service account for the GCP provider with the following IAM permissions (no conditions):

- Billing Account User
- Project Creator
- Service Config Editor *(I've added this thinking it would resolve the issue based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/verify-domain-name) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/control-api-access) doc page.)*

The Google account that is the owner of the organization has verified the domain in question, yet I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Error creating DomainMapping: googleapi: Error 403: Caller is not authorized to administer the domain 'testing.redacted.com'. If you own 'testing.redacted.com', you can obtain authorization by verifying ownership of the domain, or any of its parent domains, via the Webmaster Central portal: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification?domain=testing.redacted.com. We recommend verifying ownership of the largest scope you wish to use with subdomains (eg. verify 'example.com' if you wish to map 'subdomain.example.com').

I've also tried adding the service account's email as a user in the Google Search Console to the domain to no avail.

Comment: Does it work without the service account?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I've only tried with the service account and I'm worried about screwing up the state if I run the apply with different credentials.

Comment: You should be able to destroy it afterwards and then reapply from the service account later.

Comment: After you verification process of the  'testing.redacted.com'.  You added the service account, what role you assigned into this service account? Try to grant service config owner role to the service account.

Comment: @ShawnDiWu thanks, I've tried with `Service Config Editor` originally. Do you think changing to `Service Config Owner`  makes a difference?

Comment: Actually，I found some use cases from internally GCP suggest to grant 'project owner ' right. Since it is GCP community, It is difficult for me to reproduce the issue. let me know if it works, Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is rather simple but sort of hidden in the docs. You need to add your service account email as owner of the domain.

1. Go [here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home)
2. Select the property you want
3. Tap the "Add an owner" button at the bottom of the page and add the email address (e.g. terraform@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com)

Comment: Thanks!!!! Should be the accepted answer. Worked instantly

Comment: This sucks. Is there a way to terraform the webmaster config part? Of all GCP services App Engine has the strangest dumbest quirks.

Comment: Looks like someone tried to support terraforming this: https://github.com/hectorj/terraform-provider-googlesiteverification